# How To store a data in variable in a class function and then access it outside

Tags: php, function, oop, php-5.3

I am trying to create a page where it will load values from the database and display it. However, I have used classes instead of normal functions.

Following is the middle code I am executing

```
if($_GET['page'] == "tip" && isset($_GET['id']))
{
    static $title;
    static $status;
    static $featured_image;
    static $excerpt;

    include("config.php");

    class Tip Extends Connection
    {
        public function show()
        {
            $query = ' SELECT status, title, featured_image, excerpt from tips WHERE id = "'.$_GET['id'].'" ';
            $connection = $this->establish_connection();
            $data = $connection->query($query);
            $connection->close();

            if($data->num_rows > 0)
            {
                while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $status = $row['status'];
                    $featured_image = $row['featured_image'];
                    $excerpt = $row['excerpt'];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'No Data Found'));
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    $tip = new Tip();
    $tip->show();
}
```

The above code is getting executed at the very first when the page is loaded after that I am trying to display variable in HTML input as below.

```
<input type="text" autofocus id="tip_title" class="tip_title round form-control" placeholder="What's the title of your Post?" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="tip_title">
```

It's not showing error as well as also not displaying the data. Just wanted to undertsand that here is my code going wrong.

Comment: in `config.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$title` is not in the scope of your method `show()`.

Just add `global $title` inside the method.

However i suggest declaring variables as properties of your class `Tip` and access them using `$tip->title`;

Comment: Worked Perfectly

Comment: How to declare them as properties can you guide?

Comment: Great. properties are defined inside the class just like methods, just omit the keyword function: public(or private, or protected) $title;

Comment: that's because private properties aren't visible outside of the class; try to set it public.

Answer (score 0):

If the 4 static variables were meant to be object properties then you need to define them in the class:

```
class Tip Extends Connection
{
    public $title;
    public $status;
    public $featured_image;
    public $excerpt;

... public function show()...
```

Your `show()` method doesn't return anything, so my assumption is that you just wanted to call the show method once which would populate the public properties, and then you display the value of these properties in some other places.

If the properties are defined as public you can then access them directly on the object:

```
$tipObject = new Tip();
$tipObject ->show();
echo $tipObject ->title; // no dollar sign after $this->
```

Additionally if they are defined as static like in the example below you can access them without an object created by using only the class name:

```
class Tip Extends Connection
{
    public static $title;
    public static $status;
    public static $featured_image;
    public static $excerpt;

    ...
}

echo Tip::$title; // with the dollar sign after ::
```